# iOS: layout constraint with hidden views

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Say I have two views aligned to bottom:

```
V:[Label1]-10-[Label2]-20-|
```

There is 10 points spacing between `Label1` and `Label2`, 20 points spacing between `Label2` and bottom.

Now, in some cases, I need to hide `Label2`, and in this case, I want to have:

```
V:[Label1]-15-|
```

That is, with `Label2` being hidden, `Label1` has 15 points spacing to bottom.

I'm setting this up in storyboard, I'm thinking of making the 15 points spacing having lower priority and hide `Label2` as needed, but it doesn't seem to work.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: The approach I usually take is to create 2 sets of constraints for each state. Then when hiding the view you can toggle the active flag of each constraint. Would that work for you?

Comment: @andrehungaro yes that would work, I'm more thinking towards a way that requires minimum coding (ie. storyboard does all the job).

Comment: I see. Since hiding views doesn't affect their constraints, I'm afraid storyboards doesn't provide us that kind of conditional behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm setting this up in storyboard

Basically, you can't. You will have to use code to manage these constraints. When you hide Label2, also swap out the first set of constraints and swap in the second ones. When you show Label2, also swap out the second set of constraints and swap in the first ones. This is perfectly standard procedure.

In fact, I have an example project that effectively shows how to do exactly what you're describing:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch01p032constraintSwapping/ConstraintSwapping/ViewController.swift

As you can see, we configure in advance the constraints for when the view `v2` is present and for when it is absent, and just swap them when we remove or reinsert `v2`.

Answer (score 1):

By keeping that low priority constraint you mentioned, the shorter solution I've found for that was:

```
@IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!
var constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]? = nil

func foo() {
    if needsToHideView2 {
        constraints = view2.constraints
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(view2.constraints)
    }
    if needsToShowView2 {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, hiding a view only affects associated constraints in a `UIStackView`. This is the case because `UIStackView` adds and removes constraints automatically when a view is hidden.

The best way to approach this is by having two sets of constraints and adding/removing each set as needed. I usually create these constraints in 
a storyboard and have one set not installed by default. I then create `IBOutlets` to each constraint involved so that I can easily reference them in code:

```
if button.isHidden {
    self.view.addConstraint(self.hiddenConstraint)
    self.view.removeConstraint(self.visibleConstraint)      
} else {
    self.view.removeConstraint(self.hiddenConstraint)
    self.view.addConstraint(self.visibleConstraint)
}
```

Comment: "Unfortunately, hiding a view does not affect the associated constraints" It does if the view is an arranged view within a UIStackView.

Comment: True. But that's only because a UIStackView is adding and removing constraints for you. I'll edit to be more technically accurate...

Comment: True of course. And it wouldn't help the OP because his constraints also need to change in a more complicated way than you'd want to configure in a stack view.

Answer (score 0):

If it's reasonable in your situation, set up your storyboard with both Label1 and Label2 and BOTH the layouts active.

For `V:[Label1]-10-[Label2]-20-|` set Label2 leading and trailing constraint priorities to required (1000)

For `V:[Label1]-15-|` set Label1 trailing constraint lower (maybe 750)

Then, at some appropriate place (viewDidLoad, layoutSubviews, updateConstraints, etc.), if you don't need Label2, just remove it from its superview.